# How to prove the contiunty of Thomae's by the concept of general topology?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

> The function is
>
> $f(x)= \begin{cases} 
> 1/n \quad &\text{if $x= m/n$ in simplest form;} \\
> 0 \quad &\text{if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.} 
> \end{cases} $
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous at every irrational point in $(0,1)$ and disconnect at every rational point in $(0,1)$.

I want to use the definition about continuous  for a topology space that

> Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_1)$ be topological spaces and f a function
>   from X into Y . Then $f : (X,\mathcal{T}) → (Y,\mathcal{T}_1)$ is said to be a continuous mapping if
>   for each $U\in\mathcal{T}_1$; $f^{-1}\left(U\right )\in \mathcal{T}$

but it seems not work for a single  point. The preimage of $1/n$ seems not open or closed in $\mathbb Q$ but I don't have idea about how to prove it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Before working on a problem about continuity at individual points, you need to look up the definition of continuity at a point.

Comment: @frame99: I don't understand your comment at all. Dr. Blass is indicating that the definition of continuity you have laid out is not the one you need to answer this question.

Comment: One should always be wise and use the most useful (equivalent) definition!